# Linux: share permissions between users for SVN folders

Tags: linux, apache, svn, cron

On a Ubuntu machine I've setup a SVN repository, served with Apache.
All the SVN repository folders and subfolders (located under /var/svn/repos/) belongs to `www-data` user and group:

```
drwxr-xr-x 7 www-data www-data 4096 gen 21 10:38 software_repository
```

`www-data` is the Apache user.
Next I've a cron job that makes a nightly svnadmin dump of the repository, using my home user, let's say `john_doe` (joining the `www-data` group too). svnadmin dump command (and more...) are contained in a sh file called by the crond.
During cron job or launching it manually using user `john_doe` I get:

```
svnadmin: E160052: Revprop caching for '/var/svn/repos/sw/software_repository/db' disabled because SHM infrastructure for revprop caching failed to initialize.
svnadmin: E000013: Can't open file '/var/svn/repos/sw/software_repository/db/rev-prop-atomics.mutex': Permission denied
```

Because of `Permission denied` error, I've run the same sh script prepending `sudo` command, and everything works fine.
So, we have 2 possibilities:

1. Understand where the SVN error come from.
2. Change permissions in a correct way for the `john_doe` user, used by cron.

For point #1 I've done some Google search but I've found nothing...
For point #2, I think the correct way is not to set all permissions (recursively) of the group `www-data` to all SVN folders and subfolders. What it could be done is to share permissions on SVN folders between `www-data` user and `john_doe`. Or give to the `www-data` group the same permissions (recursively) of the `www-data` user. Or something else, but for both solutions I've no idea of the correct command or configuration setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved running command:

```
chmod -R g=u software_repository
```

This fix is for solution 2. By the way I've no clue where the SVN errors come from...